# como agrupar elementos de una lista con base a criterios?

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo una lista de mas de 2400 elementos (código penal) ejemplo

```
Articulo 3o Principios de las sanciones penales
La imposicion de la pena o de la medida de seguridad respondera a los principios de necesidad proporcionalidad y razonabilidad
El principio de necesidad se entendera en el marco de la prevencion y conforme a las instituciones que la desarrollan
Articulo 4o Funciones de la pena
La pena cumplira las funciones de prevencion general retribucion justa prevencion especial reinsercion social y proteccion al condenado
La prevencion especial y la reinsercion social operan en el momento de la ejecucion de la pena de prision
```

lo que busco hacer es agrupar los elementos de la lista en articulo y contenido, algo asi

```
[['articulo','contenido'],[...],[...]
```

aunque esta un tanto complejo para mi, ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?
esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora

```
x = ''
y = ''
xx=[]
yy=[]

for i in dts:
  if 'Articulo' in i:
    x += i
    y=''
  else:
    y += i
    x=''
  xx.append(x)
  yy.append(y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar una expresión regular como lo siguiente y aunque la respuesta da lo que pides, puedes adoptarlo a tu solución:

```
# no necesitas instalar este paquete, solo úsalo
import re

texto = '''Articulo 3o Principios de las sanciones penales
La imposicion de la pena o de la medida de seguridad respondera a los principios de necesidad proporcionalidad y razonabilidad
El principio de necesidad se entendera en el marco de la prevencion y conforme a las instituciones que la desarrollan
Articulo 4o Funciones de la pena
La pena cumplira las funciones de prevencion general retribucion justa prevencion especial reinsercion social y proteccion al condenado
La prevencion especial y la reinsercion social operan en el momento de la ejecucion de la pena de prision'''


# Patrón de expresión regular para buscar los artículos
patron_articulo = r'Articulo \d+[a-z]?'

# Separar los artículos del contenido utilizando expresiones regulares
resultados = re.findall(patron_articulo, texto)

# Crear una lista de listas con el formato [['articulo', 'contenido'], [...], [...]]
lista_articulos = []
for i in range(len(resultados)):
    if i < len(resultados) - 1:
        articulo = resultados[i]
        contenido = texto.split(resultados[i])[1].split(resultados[i+1])[0].strip()
    else:
        articulo = resultados[i]
        contenido = texto.split(resultados[i])[1].strip()
    lista_articulos.append([articulo, contenido])


print(lista_articulos)

# Imprimir la lista de artículos
# for articulo in lista_articulos:
#     print(articulo)
```

Espero que te pueda ayudar, saludos

Comment: :) sos el mejor!